# steps to convert LightSwitch app to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

i'm trying to replace a LightSwitch app with MVC using VS2012.
any suggestions on what steps need to be followed?

Answer (score 0):

There are no explicit or easy steps to do this. ..

At most you can reuse the LightSwitch backend datasource as an OData source and it would be better to upgrade your LightSwitch project to the latest VS2012 update 3 version (you may need to add a dummy HTML client) so as to ensure that your LightSwitch datasource produces JSON rather than Atom format.

Once you've got the above done you probably want to look at UI components like Kendo UI that will allow you to use either the Javascript version of their components or the MVC wrappers to connect to an OData backend. THere are some community form posts on KendoUI.com about connecting to OData sources.

Good luck, depending on the size of your LS application, this will be a significant task.